# How can I separate "Data" from my console application?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, class-library

I have two projects:

- Console application
- Class Library

I want the `Class library` to define the classes, create edmx files and to have a partial connection string, like:

```
<add name="BlogEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Blog.csdl|res://*/Blog.ssdl|res://*/Blog.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='{0}'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I want my Class Library to define the `csdl`, `ssdl` and `msl` files. My Console application doesn't care about the metadata, it will only define the `database`, `user` and `password`.

How can I split the connection string in two like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I can name all entities with the same name, e.g. `Entities`. My `app.config` will need to be on the Console Application, but I can use a single `ConnectionString`.

```
<add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=test;Password=test;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

The metadata can be set to `res://*/` and it will work globally. [From MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327.aspx)

> Model and mapping metadata used by the
>   Entity Framework is loaded into a
>   MetadataWorkspace. This metadata is
>   cached globally and is available to
>   other instances of ObjectContext in
>   the same application domain.

I can also force that any plug-able module will use a `ConnectionString` passing on the context constructor:

```
new Blogs.Data.Entities("name=Entities");
```

Answer (score 0):

from my memory, if you create the model in a class lib, VS will create an app.config in the lib project.

Simply merge the content of this file in the app.config of the console library.

in this scenario, you can have a "design" config in the app.config file of the lib, and a run time config in the app.config of the console application.

Comment: I want a `plug and play` lib. If I need copy the app.config that means I require access to the project files...

Comment: the config file is not compiled. It's just a text file in the application folder. If you need to setup interactively, I think there are overload of constructor of the ObjectContext class (but I may be wrong)

Answer (score 0):

Create a class in your library (e.g. `Connector`) that allows you to provide whatever connection values you will need (database, user, password). Then use this class in your console application and provide the necessary values however you see fit.